# How to vectorize an operation between a 2D array and another vector?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, cosine-similarity

I have a numpy 2D array like this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And a separate vector like this:
`[5, 6]`.

The operation in this case is `np.inner`, as part of my larger task of taking the cosine similarity between each row of the 2D array and the separate vector.

My expected output is `[np.inner([1, 2], [5, 6]), np.inner([3, 4], [5, 6]]`. I can accomplish this using `apply_along_axis`, but is there any way to vectorize this operation and make it more performant than `apply_along_axis`?

There are lots of answered questions regarding how to vectorize these types of operations between pairs of rows of two 2D arrays, but in this situation I need to vectorize the operation between one 2D array and another vector. I could turn `[5, 6]` into `[[5, 6], [5, 6]]` and then have the vectorization that way, but at large scales I need a solution where I can use the other vector itself in the operation rather than turning it into a 2D array with a bunch of row copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound like you need `np.dot'

```
In [3]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [4]: b = np.array([5, 6])

In [5]: a.dot(b)
Out[5]: array([17, 39])

In [6]: np.inner(a[0], b)
Out[6]: 17

In [7]: np.inner(a[1], b)
Out[7]: 39
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [6]: A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]); x=np.array([5,6])
```

`inner` does work with your 2d array (admittedly its documentation is a bit vague about that

```
In [7]: np.inner(A,x)                                                                            
Out[7]: array([17, 39])
```

Normally we use `np.dot` for matrix multiplication, including 1d `inner`:

```
In [8]: np.dot(A,x)                                                                              
Out[8]: array([17, 39])
```

or in newer `numpy`, the @ operator, which is also `np.matmul`.

```
In [9]: A@x                                                                                      
Out[9]: array([17, 39])
```

Both use the `last of A` sums with the 2nd to the last of B` (or the only axis of x).

The two inner calculations that you want:

```
In [10]: np.inner(A[0,:],x)                                                                      
Out[10]: 17
In [11]: np.inner(A[1,:],x)                                                                      
Out[11]: 39
```

A (2,n) array broadcasts with a (n,) array, just fine, producing a (2,n) result

```
In [12]: A * x                                                                                   
Out[12]: 
array([[ 5, 12],
       [15, 24]])
In [13]: (A * x).sum(axis=1)       # and sum on the `n` axis for inner                                                                 
Out[13]: array([17, 39])
```

`broadcasting` has the effect of repeating rows (or other dimensions), but is computationally efficient.